# extracting from list by name with dplyr

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, forecasting

I have a data table with consumptions by date of a number of products. I generated the forecast of each product, and now want to get the mean and upper 80% at period +1. The problem is the forecast object is a list with differing structures, depending on the method used, so I can't retrieve the values by indexing (I can by names with `data.table`).

This is the (dummy) data and code:

```
# load required libraries
library(data.table)
library(xts)
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)

# create random data
set.seed(1)
a <- data.table(prod = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20, TRUE), cons = sample(1:50, 20, TRUE), dt = sample(seq(as.Date("2016/06/01"), as.Date("2016/07/27"), by = "day"), 20, FALSE))

# create a time series of purchases
b <- a[, .(C=sum(cons)), by = .(dt, prod)][, x := .(list(xts(x = C, order.by = dt))), by = prod]
b <- b[, .SD[1,], by = prod]

# create a "reference" timeseries
dts <- xts(order.by = seq(as.Date("2016/06/01"), as.Date("2016/07/27"), by = "day"))

# merge reference and calculated timeseries, so zeros appear
b[, x2 := .(list(merge.xts(dts, x[[1]], fill = 0))), by = prod]

# calculate forecast for each extended timeseries
b[, fc := .(list(forecast(x2[[1]]))), by = prod]
```

Now I want to extract the mean and upper level. The problem is that the mean **sometimes** is located in slot 2 of the list, and sometimes not, so I have to call it by name. In `data.table` I do:

```
b[, mn := fc[[1]]$mean[1], by = prod]
b[, up := fc[[1]]$upper[1,1], by = prod]
```

but if I attempt to do same in `dplyr`, then I get a closure error:

```
b  %>% mutate(mnD = .$fc[[1]]$mean[1])
## Error: invalid subscript type 'closure'

b  %>% mutate(mnD = fc[[1]]$mean[1])
## Error: invalid subscript type 'closure'
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve this in `dplyr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combining with `map_dbl()` from the `purrr` package will work as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
b %>% as_data_frame() %>% mutate(mnD = map_dbl(fc, ~ .$mean[1]))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 7
#>    prod         dt     C         x        x2             fc       mnD
#>   <chr>     <date> <int>    <list>    <list>         <list>     <dbl>
#> 1     B 2016-07-17    47 <S3: xts> <S3: xts> <S3: forecast> 2.5241999
#> 2     C 2016-07-14    33 <S3: xts> <S3: xts> <S3: forecast> 1.1749266
#> 3     E 2016-06-30     7 <S3: xts> <S3: xts> <S3: forecast> 0.5952119
#> 4     D 2016-06-24    20 <S3: xts> <S3: xts> <S3: forecast> 3.3695962
#> 5     A 2016-07-04    18 <S3: xts> <S3: xts> <S3: forecast> 0.8421001
```

Aside, `as_data_frame()` is not needed, but added to print the results in a neat way. Without it, the list columns print all data.

Comment: No need to, just so it prints properly. Without it, the list columns print in full (rather than <S3: xxx>). But good reminder - I'll edit to mention this.